# Upload IPhone app to device instead of other app

Tags: iphone, xcode, certificate, app-store-connect, ios-provisioning

So I'm not that familiar with the process of Provisioning profiles and certificates.

Currently I have one app I'm developing that I can upload to my device.

Now, for testing reasons, I want to write a very simple app and to upload it to my device as well. The thing is, is that I don't want to configure another app in iTunes connect and provisioning profiles, so I thought maybe it's possible just to change the bundle identifier of the second app to be the same as the first.

However, in XCode I get the following error :

```
"Code Sign error: The identity 'iPhone Developer' doesn't match any identity in any profile"
```

Any way to make this happen?

Answer (score 1):

If you set the bundle identifier of the 2nd app to be the same as the 1st, the 2nd app will replace the 1st one on your phone.

If you want the ability to have both apps installed at the same time, you need a new app id.

But you don't want to create a new app id for each test project.
The idea is to recreate the *Team provisioning profile* available for the *Company* developer program (I guess you subscribed to the individual developer program).

1. Create a new app id with bundle identifier set to `*`
2. Create the provisioning profile associated to this app id
3. Download and install this generic provisioning profile

With this wildcard profile, you will be able to install any test application.

Comment: Hi, so couple things : 1. first, I don't mind the second app will replace the first one, I just want to test something just once, and then I'll reinstate the first app.(but I still get the error above)  2. my app id is P4EEER26D8.com.test.*   , so it does end with *, what else should I do here ?   thx!

Comment: If your first app bundle identifier is `com.something`, use the same bundle identifier in your second project. Then select the associated provisioning profile in the "Code signing" section of your target settings.

Answer (score 0):

Please request a certificate to apple through your paid developer account, generate a provisioning profile and install this in mac as well as in your device. then choose your provisioning profile and build and run your app through this provision.then it will install in device. There are details in **developer.apple.com** regarding to this. If you feels confusion please mail me sandeep.kniit@gmail.com. i will reply you asap.

Comment: The idea is to keep the discussion on SO, that way other people can benefit from answers in the future. Taking it to one-on-one email conversations won't do a lot to help others. Just a friendly tip.

Comment: Hi, I already have a PP and one working app that can be uploaded to a device. I was asking for an advice how to upload a second app without doing all this setup again, by maybe using the first app bundle identifier. if that's not possible, maybe other suggestions. thanks

Comment: Hello Idan,if you uses same bundle identifier it will replaces the first app by second. So why not you generate a new provisioning profile with new bundle identifier and do the same things that you have performed in first app. There is no other way to do it through bypass. thanks

Comment: @code_burger : thanks. i m new on stackoverflow. i will remember it.